Find the one sentence that is wrong in the following proof.
Here is the Proposition that is being proved:
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$ with dim $V = n \geq 1,$ and let $T \in \mathcal{L}(V).$ Then $T$ has an eigenvalue.
Here is the attempted proof:
Since dim $V = n \geq 1,$ there is a nonzero vector $v \in V.$ Consider the list $(v, Tv, T^2v, \dots , T^n v ),$ which has length $n + 1.$ Since dim $V = n,$ this list is linearly dependent. Thus there is a linear relation $$a_0v + a_1 Tv + a_2 T^2 v + \dots + a_n T^nv = 0$$
with not all $a_i$ being zero. Let $$p(z) = a_0 + a_1 z + \dots + a_n z^n \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb C).$$
Then $p$ is not the zero polynomial and $p(T)v = 0.$ Let $m$ be the largest $i$ such that $a_i \neq 0;$ we have $p \in \mathcal{P}_m(\mathbb C).$ Since every polynomial $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb C)$ factors into linear factors, we may write $$p(z) = \alpha (z - \lambda_1)(z - \lambda_2) \dots (z - \lambda_m)$$ for some complex numbers $\alpha, \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_m.$ Thus $$p(T)v = (T - \lambda_1 I)(T - \lambda_2 I) \dots (T - \lambda_m I)v = 0,$$
where $I \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is the identity operator.
If $(T - \lambda_i I)$ is injective for every i, then $p(T)$ is injective, since the composition of injective maps is injective.
But $p(T)v = 0,$ so $p(T)$ is not injective, so at least one $T - \lambda_i I$ is not injective. For this i, we have $(T - \lambda_i I)v = 0$ and so $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_i.$ Therefore, $T$ has an eigenvalue.
My questions are:
Is the statement I made bold above is the wrong statement in the proof? If so, why it is wrong? Is there a counterexample to it?
If the statement I made bold above is not the wrong statement in the proof, what is the wrong statement in the proof?
Could someone help me answer those questions please?

Wrong sentence:

For this $i$, we have $(T-\lambda_i I)v=0$.

This need not happen. The only guarantee as you claimed is one of the operators $T-\lambda_i I$ is not injective and hence its kernel is non-zero. That non-zero element in its kernel would be the eigen vector.

is the bold statement a correct statement or not?

Of course, yes. Composition of injective maps is injective.

so the problem is that we can not conclude that this $v$ is an eigenvector but we still can conclude that there exists an eigenvalue? Am I correct?

Yes. Although $v$ may not be eigen vector, there may exist a vector which is eigen vector.

@Yathi - You can remove the word "may" from that last comment. As you said in your answer, a non-zero vector from the kernel of that operator is an eigenvector of $T$.

To be clear, we do have $(T-\lambda_iI)w=0$ for some $w$. We simply aren't guaranteed that $w$ is the same $v$ that we started with. Which doesn't affect the conclusion that $T$ has some eigenvalue. The proof doesn't use "first v" being equal to "second v" anywhere in the proof.

Yes. You are right. The $w$ need not be $v$. The only guarantee, as I said, that there exists at least one such $w$.

The mistake in your proof is that you don't know that your original $v$ is in the kernel of your non-invertible $T-\lambda_i I$. So, as @Yathi stated in their answer, the statement that is wrong is

For this $i$, $(T-\lambda_i I)v=0$

But that's not too bad of a mistake. You were correct up to that point, so "$(T-\lambda_i I)$ is not injective" is correct. So you can instead say "That means that there is some non-zero vector $w$ such that $(T-\lambda_i I)w=0$, so $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $T$".
(I'm assuming here that you're comfortable with injectivity and kernels of linear maps, and the different equivalent ways to show that something is an eigenvalue. If you're still uncertain on those, perhaps you could explicitly identify which steps are causing you trouble?)
What you can't do is say that the vector you picked at the beginning is one of the vectors in the kernel of $(T-\lambda_i I)$. Perhaps you weren't aware that you were implying that when you re-used the variable $v$ there? In that case you could also think of the mistake this way: In math you cannot re-use a variable to refer to something if it's already referring to something else.
And if you step back and look at the proof the way you presented it: Your $v$ was originally chosen knowing only that it was non-zero. The fact that you concluded that this rather arbitrary vector must be an eigenvector of $T$ looks suspicious - if your proof (as written) was correct then you would be able to pick any non-zero vector and show that it was an eigenvector! We know that that's not true, so we know there must have been a mistake somewhere in our proof.

sorry I do not understand how what you said is answering my questions, where is the sentence that contain the mistake? Did I spot it correctly? Why it is wrong?

@Yathi has explicitly identified the incorrect sentence in their answer. Also, sentence you put in bold is in fact valid, so you had not correctly spotted the incorrect sentence.

But we have an assumption at the beginning that v is nonzero, does not this contradict your first statement?

Yes, at the beginning you picked $v$ as some non-zero vector. But after that point $v$ represents some particular fixed vector. Then you do some computations and logic, and figure out (correctly) that there is some $i$ so that $T-\lambda_i I$ is not injective. That means there is some (non-zero) vector $w$ such that $(T-;ambda_i I)w = 0$, but you don't know anything else about $w$, and you certainly can't assume that it's the same vector as the $v$ you picked at the beginning.

@Hope - I did some re-writing, and added some more detail to my answer. Maybe that will clarify some things for you?

You don't know that $(T-\lambda_iI)v=0$ for any $i$. Maybe $(T-\lambda_mI)v=0$, so $v$ is an eigenvector. Of if not that, then $(T-\lambda_{m-1}I)[(T-\lambda_mI)v]=0$, so $(T-\lambda_mI)v$ is an eigenvector. Or maybe $(T-\lambda_{m-2}I)[(T-\lambda_{m-1}I)(T-\lambda_mI)v]=0$, so $(T-\lambda_{m-1}I)(T-\lambda_mI)v$ is an eigenvector, or so on.

Yeah, like you say, you can examine the chain of applications looking for the first 0, and take the one just before that and explicitly exhibit that as an eigenvector. But since the question just asks to prove that one exist one can be lazy and say "one term is not injective, so just grab something from its kernel".
